# select from over 10 tables (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, explain

Please help me in my question - I've got a query with `select` over 10 tables, but I'm waiting over 180 seconds. It's a very very bad result.
How I can optimize my query?

```
SELECT main_order.id,main_order.datetime_add,main_order.datetime_update, main_order.id_user_add, main_order.id_user_update,main_order.date_start,main_order.time_start,main_order.date_finish, main_order.time_finish,main_order.order_cashless,main_order.client_paid, main_order.`commentary`, order_addres.`addres`,order_addres.`build` , order_addres.office_or_flat,pack.name, client.name,client.company,client.phone
 FROM main_order,order_addres,pack,client,workers_salary,cash_money,loaders,auto_order,sms 
WHERE 1=1 
  AND date_finish<=:date_finish 
   OR date_finish IS NULL 
GROUP BY main_order.id
ORDER BY date_start DESC, time_start DESC
```

[EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPu9Y.jpg)

Comment: I doubt very much that you're using the right join; try using a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Using a LEFT JOIN means you'll only get 1 address per order, etc rather than a set of records with every possible address for every possible order (and similarly for all the other tables that you're joining)

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I added per values to my $where and after all operation insert to query. How I can update it by LEFT JOIN?

```
<?


        $params = array();
        $where = " WHERE 1=1"; 

        if(!empty($_GET["id"]) &&  isset($_GET["id"]))
        {
            $params["id"]=$_GET["id"];
            $where .= " AND main_order.id=:id";
        } 

        if(!empty($_GET["shop_id"]) &&  isset($_GET["shop_id"]))
        {
            $params["number_order"]=$_GET["shop_id"];
            $where .= " AND sms.number_order=:number_order AND sms.id_order=main_order.id ";
        }



        if(!empty($_GET["date_start"]) &&  isset($_GET["date_start"]))
        {
            $params["date_start"]=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET["date_start"]));
            $where .= " AND date_start>=:date_start OR date_start IS NULL"; 
        }

        if(!empty($_GET["time_start"]) &&  isset($_GET["time_start"]))
        {
            $params["time_start"]=date("H:i",strtotime($_GET["time_start"]));
            $where .= " AND time_start >=:time_start  OR time_start IS NULL";
        }

        if(!empty($_GET["date_finish"]) &&  isset($_GET["date_finish"]))
        {
            $params["date_finish"]=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET["date_finish"]));
            $where .= " AND date_finish<=:date_finish OR date_finish IS NULL";
        }

        if(!empty($_GET["time_finish"]) &&  isset($_GET["time_finish"]))
        {
            $params["time_finish"]=date("H:i",strtotime($_GET["time_finish"]));
            $where .= " AND time_finish <=:time_finish OR time_finish IS NULL";
        }

         //MANY MANY FILTER HERE I JUST CUT IT ...........................

        if(!empty($_GET["cashier"]) &&  isset($_GET["cashier"]))
        {
            $i = 1;
            $where.=" AND (";
            foreach ($_GET["cashier"] as $key )
            {
            $params["cashier$i"]=$key; 
            $where.= " cash_money.cashier=:cashier$i OR";
            $i++;
            }
            $where =  substr($where, 0, -3).")"; 
        }

            if(!empty($_GET["status"]) &&  isset($_GET["status"]))
        {
            $i = 1;
            $where.=" AND (";
            foreach ($_GET["status"] as $key )
            {
            $params["id_status$i"]=$key; 
            $where.= " main_order.id_status=:id_status$i OR";
            $i++;
            }
            $where =  substr($where, 0, -3).")"; 
        }


           @$num = (int)$_GET['row'];
        if ($num == 0)
            $num = 25;
        if (!empty($_GET['page']))
            $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
        else
            $page = 1;

            $filter_sql = "SELECT main_order.id,main_order.datetime_add,main_order.datetime_update,
            main_order.id_user_add,
            main_order.id_user_update,main_order.date_start,main_order.time_start,main_order.date_finish,
            main_order.time_finish,main_order.order_cashless,main_order.client_paid, main_order.`commentary`,
            order_addres.`addres`,order_addres.`build` , order_addres.office_or_flat,pack.name,
            client.name,client.company,client.phone
            FROM main_order,order_addres,pack,client,workers_salary,cash_money,loaders,auto_order,sms

            $where 
             GROUP BY main_order.id
         ORDER BY date_start DESC, time_start DESC  
            ";exit($filter_sql);

            $res = $pdo->prepare($filter_sql);
            if(!empty($params))
         $res->execute($params);
         else  $res->execute();

        $posts = $res->rowCount();
        $total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
        $page = intval($page);
        if (empty($page) or $page < 0)
            $page = 1;
        if ($page > $total)
            $page = $total;
        $start = $page * $num - $num;

        $res = $pdo->prepare("SELECT main_order.id,main_order.datetime_add,main_order.datetime_update,
            main_order.id_user_add,
            main_order.id_user_update,main_order.date_start,main_order.time_start,main_order.date_finish,
            main_order.time_finish,main_order.order_cashless,main_order.client_paid, main_order.`commentary`,
            order_addres.`addres`,order_addres.`build` , order_addres.office_or_flat,pack.name,
            client.name,client.company,client.phone 
            FROM main_order,order_addres,pack,client,workers_salary,cash_money,loaders,auto_order,sms

            $where 
             GROUP BY main_order.id 
         ORDER BY date_start DESC, time_start DESC LIMIT $start,$num
            ");







        if(!empty($params))
         $res->execute($params);
         else  $res->execute();
```

?>